# "Apple mobile device driver" not present in Device Manager | Device not found on Pangu?

Tags: iphone, ios, windows, driver

I'm trying to jailbreak my phone because I have important apps that I need to run that cannot be downloaded on the app store.

Neither Pangu nor iTunes are recognizing my device.  I went to apple's support site, and they said that I should be showing this driver--Apple Mobile Device Driver--in my device manager.  I'm not.

I can plug my phone in and use it to get pics off the phone, but I can't use it with iTunes or Pangu.

I can't find the driver online, which is ridiculous because these things have been around for years.  Add New Device doesn't have the phone, probably because by Windows' standard, it's working fine (I can use it as an HDD).  And I can't select "another device" and "have disk" as in XP because it's been removed from Windows 7 (that's assuming the driver were somewhere to be found locally).  In the first place, I removed the driver and deleted it because stupid Apple Support advised that I do so in their 'phone not recognized in iTunes' article.

I've reinstalled iTunes, but I'm also going to now UNINSTALL iCloud, iTunes, and anything published by Apple off my PC.  Then, maybe I should start disabling my USB drivers?  Any other ideas?

Comment: My guess would be that whatever hooky software you have to enable the non-Apple functionality is undermining the official drivers.

Comment: @Tetsujin I agree.  I think it's some generic Windows driver.

Comment: I'd be wary that a simple 'uninstall' of other apps/processes is not going to restore the status quo. I'f you've a spare drive/partition, it might be simpler to see if a clean OS + iTunes has the same issues, putting fault at whatever is going on at the phone, or OS.